# kernel source code location in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vmware, device-driver, fedora11

I am working in `Windows` and running `fedora` through VMware.

By default, the kernel source tree should be in `usr/src/` directory. Instead I could find only an empty directory called kernels. The actual source code is missing there.

When browsing I thought it might be in other directories like `/boot`. But I couldn't find source tree there as well.

I need to modify system call tables for which I should be able to access those source codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to install the `kernel-devel` package.

On Fedora, all of the software is managed through a system called the Red Hat Package Manager ([RPM](http://www.rpm.org/)). Every file (other than user data and other transient files like logs and such) is "owned" by a package. The `ls` command is from `coreutils`, the kernel is probably from `kernel` and [BZFlag](http://bzflag.org/) (the greatest Linux game ever) is provided by the `bzflag` package.

In the good old days, you would try to install software by using the `rpm` command (type "`man rpm`" for more information) and giving it the path to an RPM file that you had downloaded. The `rpm` command would then dutifully respond by informing you that you first need to satisfy 33 prerequisites. Then you would go download those 33 prerequisites and try to install them, only to find that each of those had their own prerequisites. And so on.

These days, Fedora has a nice set of online repositories of packages (and you can add others for third party software), and a program called [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/) that can download databases of all the packages, and you tell yum "install package foo for me" (by typing something like "`yum install kernel-devel`") and it goes and figures out that in order to install that package, you need a bunch of other prerequisite packages, and so on. It then automatically downloads and installs everything you need, and away you go. For more information on the various incantations that make `yum` go, see "`man yum`").

Comment: What is that actually.. can u brief on that

Comment: Most GNU/Linux distributions include a system that lets you add, manage, and remove bundles of software (called "packages"). I believe Fedora uses the RPM Package Manager. It should be able to fetch the software from the internet for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Kernel source is not installed by default. You can follow e.g. the instructions [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/CustomKernel) to install the source and build your kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You might only need kernel-headers, depending what exactly it is you are doing, building drivers normally only requires the headers.

I found this page which may be of use to you [Complete Fedora Kernel Headers](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/12/14/the-complete-fedora-kernel-headers/) It mentions that the 'kernel-devel' package doesn't include everything. (that would be just too simple!) It also tells you exactly how to use the rpm package handler.

You can, (I have tried this years ago, although I use Gentoo now), just download an archive from kernel.org and unpack it in  /usr/src, but then you would have a 'vanilla' kernel without the Fedora patches.

Comment: It's there now. I just followed the link. Down votes just because someone else's website is offline for short time is a bit harsh.

Comment: what if i wanted to do some changes inside the ubuntu kernel source and rebuild that kernel ,please give me solutions regarding how to carry out the steps to overcome on the above problem?